# basic program of Html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In this code only HTML part works but JavaScript part does not work. I can't understand the problem. I'm saving this file in `.html` extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <h1> what can javascript Do?</h1>
        <p id="demo">Javascript can change html content.</p>
        <button type="button" onclick=" myFunction()">
            Click Me!</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHtml = 'hello javascript'">
        }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove `">` from the javascript function body. `innerHTML` with capital `HTML`. See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cncd3apL/)

Comment: @connexo No, it should be `myFunction()` otherwise the function will not be called when clicked. Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/cncd3apL/1/)

Comment: @YogitaVerma consider selecting answer as best answer if you find any, otherwise provide your persisting problem in detail..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct syntax is `innerHTML` and not `innerHtml`, also in the last of the line you have some `">` which must be replaced by `;` (semicolon). 
Correct Syntax -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'hello javascript';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There're many syntax error in your code

first `'hello javascript'">` should be `'hello javascript';`
and later **actually it is `innerHTML` not innerHtml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <h1 id="myid" > what can javascript Do?</h1>
        <p id="demo">Javascript can change html content.</p>
        <button type="button" onclick= "myFunction()">
            Click Me!</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
        
            document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'hello javascript';
        }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```